# ¿Porque no funcionan mi fragment en mi menu deslizable?

Tags: android-studio

hola que tal quisiera saber por que mi fragmento no funciona cada que le presiono en el menu deslizable

Por ejemplo este es el codigo de mi fragment:

public class frg extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView ms, alt, to, cim;
    Button aceptar;
    EditText m, a;

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {




    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frg, container, false);
    aceptar=(Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.okey);
    ms=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.etm);
    alt=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.eta);
    to=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.etiqueta);
    m=(EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.masa);
    a=(EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.altura);
    cim=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.imc);
    aceptar.setOnClickListener(this);
    return  v;



}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    try{
            switch (v.getId()){

                case R.id.okey:
                double total, m1, a1;
                String txt=m.getText().toString();
                String tx2=a.getText().toString();

                m1=Double.parseDouble(txt);
                a1=Double.parseDouble(tx2);

                total=m1/(a1*a1);
                to.setText(""+total);

                if (total>=1.69){
                    cim.setText("Estas bien pinche gordo :v");
                }

                break;
            }


        } catch (Exception e){

    }
}
```

}

y aqui es donde lo mando a llamar en el codigo del menu deslizable:

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

```
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager f1 = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        f1.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fondito, new frg()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Buen día, yo en estos casos uso un *FrameLayout* para colocar el fragmento.

Este es un ejemplo de como lo uso:

> Selección en el menú

```
  public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        android.support.v4.app.Fragment frag = null;

        int id = item.getItemId();


        switch (id){
            case R.id.nav_informacion:
                frag =  Informacion.newInstance();
                break;
                }

        if(frag != null){
            CambiarFragment(frag);
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

> Método que hace el intercambio de fragments

```
 public void CambiarFragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment frag){

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        // Remplaza cualquier fragment que este en el contenedor

        transaction.replace(R.id.frameContent, frag); //frameContent es mi FrameLayout
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        transaction.commit();

    }
```

Un dato, te recomendaría usar variables más explicitas para que en un futuro no te quedes con la incógnita de que es/significan.

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso uso un viewpager2 para lograr fragments con deslizamiento, crea un activity principal que es donde se van visualizaran los fragments, dentro del xml de este activity coloca el componente viewpager2 y un tablayout si quieres que se muestre con pestañas y hazles sus instancias en tu activity con sus id. Crea tus fragments y su diseño y despues puedes implementar el siguiente codigo.

Primero haz una clase de ayuda que extienda de FragmentStateAdapter, como la siguiente.

```
public class ViewPagerFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
    private ArrayList<Fragment> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

public ViewPagerFragmentAdapter (@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle) {
    super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new Fragment1(); // Aqui es el nombre de la tus fragments
        case 1:
            return new Fragment2();
        case 2:
            return new Fragment3();
        case 3:
            return new Fragment4();
        case 4:
            return new Fragment5();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 5; // Numero de fragmentos que se van a mostrar
}


public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return arrayList.get(position);
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    arrayList.add(fragment);
}
```

}

Despues en tu activity principal que servira como contenedor de esos fragments haz lo siguiente.

```
public class Escritura extends AppCompatActivity {


ViewPager2 myViewPager2;
ViewPagerFragmentAdapterEscritura adapter;
TabLayout tabLayout;


   @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myViewPager2 = (ViewPager2) findViewById(R.id.componenteViewPager2);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.componenteTabLayout);

    adapter = new ViewPagerFragmentAdapter (getSupportFragmentManager(), getLifecycle());

    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment1());
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment2());
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment3());
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment4());
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment5());


    myViewPager2.setOrientation(ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL); // Orientacion
    myViewPager2.setAdapter(adapter);

    new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, myViewPager2, (tab, position) ->
            tab.setText("ESCRITURA " + (position + 1))
    ).attach();
}
```

}

Tu xml quedaria de la siguiente forma.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" />

<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/viewPagerEscritura"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tab_layout" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Quedaria de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el espacio en blanco se verian tus fragments y al deslizar hacia la derecha o izquierda puedes pasar de uno a otro. Espero que te sea de ayuda, cualquier duda aqui estamos.